# Android Fragments in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm kinda confused about the whole Fragment-way-of-thinking. I've followed a tutorial on how to create a `ViewPager` with `Fragments` like the `Google Play` app.

I have TabFragment class like this one:

```
public class SwipeyTabFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        Log.e("FRAGMENT: ", "Hello World!"); 
    }

    public static Fragment newInstance(String title) {
        SwipeyTabFragment f = new SwipeyTabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_swipeytab, null);
        final String title = getArguments().getString("title");
        ((TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(title);
        return root;
    }
}
```

I know that the `onCreateView` method initialize the layout and the controlls like `Button`, `ListView` and so on.

Over to my `FragmentAdapter`

```
private class SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements SwipeyTabsAdapter {

        private final Context mContext;

        public SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return SwipeyTabFragment.newInstance(TITLES[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        public TextView getTab(final int position, SwipeyTabs root) {
            TextView view = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.swipey_tab_indicator, root, false);
            view.setText(TITLES[position]);
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                }
            });
            return view;
        }

    }
```

This will just construct a new Tab based on a String-Array, which will set the text and the header of the `Fragment`.

So this is where I get confused. Say for instance that I want several fragments with different layout, and different ways of interacting when the user presses on `Button`, `Picture` or whatever. How can I do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the 'user presses button' stuff is handled in the fragments, you can call back to the `Activity` of course when you need to (see [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)). 
You have to create different fragment classes for different layouts, logic. etc. and return them to the ViewPager in `getItem`. You could have a FirstPageFragment and a SecondPageFragment, then return them (depending on the index) in `getView`. This only makes sense if those fragments have different functionalities of course. 
Hope it's clear what I mean ;)

EDIT: as to your comment:

I don't know what exactly you want to do, but you have your `SwipeyTabFragment` already defined in it's own file. Take this then, modify it, give it another layout and other functionality, then call it OtherFragment or whatever. Let's say you want to have 2 different 'pages' in your App - the `getCount()` method in your adapter defines the amount of 'pages' in your `ViewPager`, so let's let it return two. 
In the `getItem()` method, `if` `position` is 0, let it return your `SwipeyFragment`, `else` (`position` is 1) let it return your new `OtherFragment`. Now you have a `ViewPager` with 2 different Fragments that can serve totally different purposes.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have time to give me some basic code samples, especially for the getItem method, am not sure on how I should do this.